# elastic search sort not working

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Hi This is my sample output from elastic search

```
"table":{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "label":"First Label",
         "value":"10"
      },
      {  
         "label":"1st Label",
         "value":"9"
      }
   ],
   "details":"Examples set on MSRP, your actual payment may vary based on price set by dealer."
}
```

And i wish to sort this in the ascending order, either thru the colunm label or through value.

The search options i tried are

```
sort = [{"data.label" : {"order" : "asc", "mode" : "min", "nested_path" : "data"}}];
sort = [{ "table.data": {"order": "asc"}]
```

But, I am not getting the expected sorted result

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you got the solution for this problem? Facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort part of the query should be -

```
"sort": { "label":   { "order": "desc" }}
```

or

```
"sort": { "value":   { "order": "desc" }}
```

or

```
"sort": [
        { "label":   { "order": "desc" }},
        { "value": { "order": "desc" }}
    ]
```

Below is the mapping, docs and subsequent query to get inner sorted elements.

```
PUT /table
{
  "mappings": {
    "data": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "subjects": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "name": { "type": "string"},
            "marks":{ "type": "integer"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /table/data/1?pretty 
{
  "name":"Ram",
  "subjects":[
    { 
      "name":"English",
      "marks":13
    },
    { 
      "name":"Hindi",
      "marks":12
    }
    ]
}
PUT /table/data/2?pretty 
{
  "name":"Sam",
  "subjects":[
    { 
      "name":"Biology",
      "marks":83
    },
    { 
      "name":"Maths",
      "marks":68
    }
    ]
}

PUT /table/data/3?pretty 
{
  "name":"Jim",
  "subjects":[
    { 
      "name":"Chemistry",
      "marks":96
    },
    { 
      "name":"Geology",
      "marks":58
    }
    ]
}

GET table/data/_search
{
 "query":{
   "nested":{
     "path":"subjects",
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
     "inner_hits":{
       "sort":{
         "subjects.marks":{
           "order":"asc"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried with all combinations and its not working. Should we go for nested sort?

Comment: Can you please put up the complete query you are making!!

Comment: Please find the query url -                                                      
 <url>/_search?q="{"filtered":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"ids":{"values":["search_key"]}}]}"&sort={ "value":   { "order": "asc" }}

Comment: @Arjun `sort=value:desc` or `sort=value:asc` or similar stuff would do then. What I had mentioned earlier was meant for CURL requests.

Comment: `http://localhost:9200/table/data/_search?q={filtered:{filter:{bool:{must:[{label:{values:["search_key"]}}]}&sort=value:asc&pretty` - This is just fine for me.

Comment: I have tried all these.Its an inner nested entity. There is an entity "table" and there is another entity "data" which has array of label and Value

Comment: Hi Rajeev, looks like the sorting is happening for the entire json record and my expectation is to sort only the inner array

Comment: Have edited the answer to sort only the inner array. There are a couple of prerequisites to achieve this as would be clear from the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Use URL parameter

```
POST /index/_search?sort=table.data:asc
{}
```

2. Use Body

```
POST /index/_search
{
    "sort":[{"table.data": "asc"}],
    ...
}
```

or

```
POST /index/_search
{
    "sort":[{"table.data": {"order": "asc"}}],
    ...
}
```